# Disabled Package Manager Console because of error in reading packages.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

Didn't find a solution for my problem on the net. My `Package Manager Console` is disabled because it says it can't read `packages.config.`

```
An error occurred while reading file 'filepath\packages.config': There are duplicate packages: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
```

I know it says there are duplicate packages but there's not. On the net, there's solution for a failed restore or a couldn't find the package.config file. Nothing remotely close to my issue.

I am trying to download `typeahead.js`. That's why I need the PMC.

Couldn't help but ask the community. Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: "Kindly help."   so commanding. Remove all the lines from your packages file and try again. Now add the lines back one at a time, retrying after each line, to find out which one is the problem. Once you've found which one is the problem, you'll know what to google for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open packages.config in notepad or notepad++.
You'll find there are two WebApi.Core references. Delete one of them. Should work.
Thanks.